# how to change date format 2017-08-14T18:30:00.000Z to Tue ,14 Aug 17 in ionic

Tags: angularjs, date, ionic-framework

i want to convert this date from 2017-08-14T18:30:00.000Z to Tue ,14 Aug 17. i have tried this solution moment(2017-08-14T18:30:00.000Z).format('ddd MMM YY') but i got this Tue Aug 17.

Comment: can u try this format moment(2017-08-14T18:30:00.000Z).format('DDD, DD MMM YY')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple...

**Just use this:**

```
moment('2017-08-14T18:30:00.000Z').format('ddd, MMM YY')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
new Date('2017-08-14T18:30:00.000Z').toDateString();
```

Comment: it will say undefined with moment(2017-08-14T18:30:00.000Z)toDateString()

Comment: You don't need moment for this to work its javascript function.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
format('ddd, DD MMM YY')
```